# unique values for a duration in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am new in mysql, I have a table with two cols `tag_id` and `time_stamp`, I use a python connector. I need to insert new `tag_id` just only if did not insert the same `tag_id` in last 5 min (or some other duration). How can I do that using python mysql.connector?

create table:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='test',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root')

    mySql_Create_Table_Query = """CREATE TABLE tags ( 
                             Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                             tag_id varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                             time_stamp Datetime NOT NULL,
                             PRIMARY KEY (Id)) """

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(mySql_Create_Table_Query)
    print("Laptop Table created successfully ")

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to create table in MySQL: {}".format(error))
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Insertion function:

```
def insertVariblesIntoTable(tag, time_stamp):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='test',
                                             user='root',
                                             password='root')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO tags(tag_id, time_stamp )
                                VALUES (%s, %s) """

        recordTuple = (tag, time_stamp)
        cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, recordTuple)
        connection.commit()
        print("Record inserted successfully into tags table")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do a query of the table like this:

```
import arrow

check = '''select max(timestamp) from tags where tag_id = {}'''
try:
  with conn.cursor() as curs:
    curs.execute(check.format(tag_id))
    max_time = curs.fetchone()
    if max_time <= arrow.utcnow().shift(minutes=-5).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'):
      #run the inserts
    else:
      pass
```